# Dropdowns not bound to ng-model in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Something very basic I am missing but I am not able to figure out . I have three fields in a view , two of them are dropdowns.

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="GroupName" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Group Name : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input ng-model="referenceEdit.groupName" id="GroupName" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="GroupType" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Group Type : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select name="selGroupType" id="selGroupType" class="form-control" ng-change="referenceEdit.populateGroupTypeDetails(selGroupType)" ng-options="groupType.value for groupType in referenceEdit.groupTypes track by groupType.id" ng-model="referenceEdit.groupType"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="GroupAssignmentMethod" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Group Assignment Method : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select name="selGroupAssignmentMethod" id="selGroupAssignmentMethod" class="form-control" ng-options="assignmentMethod.id for assignmentMethod in referenceEdit.assignmentMethods track by assignmentMethod.value" ng-model="referenceEdit.assignmentMethod"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now in controller , I am getting the results for these drop downs in this way :

```
var row_details = GroupMembershipReferenceServices.getReferenceDataRow();

referenceDataDropDownService.getDropDown(REFERENCE_DATA_CONSTANTS.GROUP_TYPE).success(function (result) {
    $scope.referenceEdit.groupTypes = result;
    $scope.referenceEdit.groupype = row_details.grp_typ;
}).error(function (result) {
    alert("Unable to retrieve dropdown values");
});

referenceDataDropDownService.getDropDown(REFERENCE_DATA_CONSTANTS.GROUP_ASSIGNMENT_METHOD).success(function (result) {
    $scope.referenceEdit.assignmentMethods = result;
    $scope.referenceEdit.assignmentMethod = row_details.grp_assgnmnt_mthd;
}).error(function (result) {
    alert("Unable to retrieve dropdown values");
});
```

Problem is values are getting populated , like

[image]

and we are displaying the values accordingly. The results are like

```
[0] {id:"1",value:"Chapter Non-Event"}
[1] {id:"2",value:"NHQ Campaign"}
```

But the `row_details.grp_typ` is `"NHQ Campaign"`.

Even though I assign it , the drop down option is not selected accordingly .

Have I to assign it to the value property only ? What am I missing ?

Comment: Where is `row_details` assigned? Please add the code.

Comment: @AWolf it is added before the drop downs are populated and it holds a valid value . Please see the updates.

Comment: Create a simple demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0):

use ng-repeat instead of ng-options

eg:

```html
<select name="selGroupType" id="selGroupType" class="form-control" ng-change="referenceEdit.populateGroupTypeDetails(selGroupType)"  ng-model="referenceEdit.groupType">
<option value="-1">---</option>
<option  ng-repeat="groupType.value for groupType in referenceEdit.groupTypes track by groupType.id" value="{[{groupType.id}]}"> {[{groupType.value}]} </option></select>
```

Comment: Why do you think this would help? At the moment, I think there isn't enough code in the question to answer it.